# How to Scala flatten list of list of turples

Tags: scala

Am trying to get flatted a list of list of turples,

```
 val folders =List( (1, (List(212, 2asdad), List(213, 2asdas))),
                    (2, (List(112, asasd),  List(113, asasd6))),
                    ...
                   )

 val ouput = folders.zipWithIndex.map(sc => sc._1._2.map((sc._2, sc._1._1, _))).foreach(println)

//output = List((1, 212, 2asdad), (1, 213, 2asdas )),
//          List((2, 112, asasd), (2, 113, asasd6 )),
```

But am interested in getting a flatted List like this

```
 //output = List((1, 212, 2asdad), (1, 213, 2asdas ),
 //                 (2, 112, asasd), (2, 113, asasd6 )),
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is invalid... `[` and `]` are for generics. Do you mean `val folders =List( (1, List((212, 2asdad), (213, 2asdas))), (2, List((112, asasd),  (113, asasd))),...` or  `val folders =List( (1, (212, 2asdad), (213, 2asdas)),(2, (112, asasd),  (113, asasd)),...`

Comment: @GáborBakos - I fixed the typos, I was drowsy while posting the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is to take a type of `List[(Int, List[(Int, Symbol)])]` and transform that to a type of `List[(Int, Int, Symbol)]`. If this what you need then the following will work:

```
scala> val a = List((1,List((2,'a), (3,'b))),(2,List((3,'c), (4,'d))))
a: List[(Int, List[(Int, Symbol)])] = List((1,List((2,'a), (3,'b))), (2,List((3,'c), (4,'d))))

scala> a.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1, y._1, y._2)))
res18: List[(Int, Int, Symbol)] = List((1,2,'a), (1,3,'b), (2,3,'c), (2,4,'d))
```

Just change the `Symbol` type to what you need.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly, just some minor fix
a.zipWithIndex.flatMap(x => x._1._2.map((x._2, x._1._1,_))).foreach(println)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mika'il answer, here is the solution

```
val folders =List( (1, (List(212, 2asdad), List(213, 2asdas))),
                (2, (List(112, asasd),  List(113, asasd6))),
                ...
               )

folders.zipWithIndex.flatMap(x => x._1._2.map((x._2, x._1._1,_))).foreach(println)
```

Output

```
List((1, 212,2asdad), (1, 213, 2asdas), (2, 112, asasd), (2,113,asas6))
```